# Copy text to clipboard without using IDs

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a website that contains many different text parts that can be copied to the clipboard.

I used the script below for this.

Is there an alternative that doesn't require you to use an ID in the font tag? Because they are long pages of text and many text parts can be copied to the clipboard, it is annoying to use a new ID everytime. Everything is mixed up and additions are made regularly.

```js
function copyElementText(id) {
  var text = document.getElementById(id).innerText;
  var elem = document.createElement("textarea");
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
  elem.value = text;
  elem.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(elem);
}
```

```css
Copy this text 4Copy this text 2
```

```html
<font id="text1" onclick="copyElementText(this.id)">Copy this text 1</font>
<p>

  <font id="text2" onclick="copyElementText(this.id)">Copy this text 2</font>
  <p>

    <font id="text3" onclick="copyElementText(this.id)">Copy this text 3</font>
    <p>

      <font id="text4" onclick="copyElementText(this.id)">Copy this text 4</font>
      <p>
```

Comment: [font](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) has been obsoleted for a long time. For the question, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: No it does not. As I said I have multiple text parts that need to be copied to the clipboard.

Comment: implement event delegation and add a `copyable` identifier/class?

Answer (score 2):

2 differents way to do that:

```js
function doCopy(el)
  {
  let elTxt            = document.createElement('textarea')
  elTxt.value          = el.textContent
  elTxt.style.height   = '0px'
  elTxt.style.width    = '0px'
  elTxt.style.opacity  = '0'
  document.body.appendChild(elTxt)
  elTxt.select()
  document.execCommand('copy') 
  document.body.removeChild(elTxt)
  }
// second way :
document.querySelectorAll('.toCopy').forEach(el=>el.onclick=_=>doCopy(el))
```

```html
<p onclick="doCopy(this)">Copy this text 1</p>
<p onclick="doCopy(this)">Copy this text 2</p>

<!-- second way -->

<p class="toCopy">Copy this text 3</p>
<p class="toCopy">Copy this text 4</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also avoid creating a textarea to make your copy which allows to have a kind of animation on the execution of your copy

```js
function doCopy(el)
  {
  el.classList.add('colorBGonClickCopy')  // ==> added
  let range = document.createRange()
  range.selectNode(el)
  getSelection().removeAllRanges()
  getSelection().addRange(range)
  document.execCommand('copy') 
  setTimeout(_=>
    { 
    getSelection().removeAllRanges() 
    el.classList.remove('colorBGonClickCopy') // ==> added 
    },500)
  }
// second way :
document.querySelectorAll('.toCopy').forEach(el=>el.onclick=_=>doCopy(el))
```

```css
.colorBGonClickCopy::selection {
  background-color: #dc143c8f !important;   
  }
```

```html
<p onclick="doCopy(this)">Copy this text 1</p>
<p onclick="doCopy(this)">Copy this text 2</p>

<!-- second way -->

<p class="toCopy">Copy this text 3</p>
<p class="toCopy">Copy this text 4</p>
```

You can can also do that, but this is not exactly the same as it change the entire element background color

```js
function doCopy(el)
  {
  el.classList.add('colorBGonClickCopy')      // ==> added
  let range = document.createRange()
  range.selectNode(el)
  getSelection().removeAllRanges()
  getSelection().addRange(range)
  document.execCommand('copy') 
  setTimeout(_=>
    { 
    getSelection().removeAllRanges() 
    el.classList.remove('colorBGonClickCopy') // ==> added
    },900)
  }


// second way :
document.querySelectorAll('.toCopy').forEach(el=>el.onclick=_=>doCopy(el))
```

```css
.colorBGonClickCopy::selection {
  background-color : transparent !important;
  }
.colorBGonClickCopy {
  animation        : 700ms bgAnim forwards;
  }
@keyframes bgAnim {
  0%   { background-color: #4606128f; }
  20%  { background-color: #dc143c8f; }
  80%  { background-color: #1449dc8f; }
  100% { background-color: #3cdc148f; }
  }
```

```html
<p onclick="doCopy(this)">Copy this text 1</p>
<p onclick="doCopy(this)">Copy this text 2</p>

<!-- second way -->

<p class="toCopy">Copy this text 3</p>
<p class="toCopy">Copy this text 4</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome! Is it possible to change the sellection color?

Comment: @WJ496582  I have updated my answser with this new feature...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the event itself and its target to get the `innerText`:

```html
onclick="copyElementText(event)"
```

**Working example:**

```js
function copyElementText(event) {
  var text = event.target.innerText;
  var elem = document.createElement("textarea");
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
  elem.value = text;
  elem.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(elem);
}
```

```html
<p onclick="copyElementText(event)">Copy this text 1</p>
<p onclick="copyElementText(event)">Copy this text 2</p>
<p onclick="copyElementText(event)">Copy this text 3</p>
<p onclick="copyElementText(event)">Copy this text 4</p>
```

---

But it's better to move the inline event listener to the script.

**Working example:**

```js
function copyElementText(event) {
  var text = event.target.innerText;
  var elem = document.createElement("textarea");
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
  elem.value = text;
  elem.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(elem);
}

document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', copyElementText);
});
```

```html
<p>Copy this text 1</p>
<p>Copy this text 2</p>
<p>Copy this text 3</p>
<p>Copy this text 4</p>
```